How to return general formulas from query?
So in many cases, like:
summa(X, Y, Z) :- 
    Z #= X + Y.

You can give the most general query to return a generic solution:
?-summa(X, Y, Z).

$VAR(X)+ $VAR(Y)#= $VAR(Z).

I have a formula involving recursion (similar to factorial) and I was hoping for a general version of it; however, when I give Prolog the most general query, it gives me specific answers, like:
X = 1, Y = 1;
X = 2, Y = 5;
X = 3, Y = 19.

Does this mean Prolog cannot make a formula out of recursive things, or is there some kind of prerequisite to getting a formulaic answer?
Note, for the standard factorial rule, it has the same behavior:
factorial(1, Y) :-
    Y #= 1.
    
factorial(X, Y) :-
    X #> 1,
    Xnew #= X - 1, 
    Y #= X * Z,
    factorial(Xnew, Z).

This returns:
?- factorial(X, Y).

X = Y, Y = 1 ;
X = Y, Y = 2 ;
X = 3, Y = 6 ;
X = 4, Y = 24 ;
X = 5, Y = 120 ;
X = 6, Y = 720 ;
X = 7, Y = 5040 .


Sounds like your code is at some point calling e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=label/1

I don't disbelieve you, but I don't know where that happens. I added this above, but the factorial rule has the same behavior. Do you know how to disable that? Maybe a particular flag or something?

I cannot reproduce this. Is there something missing? When I save your factorial definition in a file and try to load it, with ?- [factorial]. I get: ERROR: factorial.pl:2:5: Syntax error: Operator expected ERROR: factorial.pl:5:5: Syntax error: Operator expected

You are observing a feature of the library which you are using.
What do you expect to see with something simpler?
?- X #= 1.

Do you expect to see this shown back to you verbatim, or do you expect it solved?
How about something slightly more complicated?
?- X #= 2*Y.

And what if we add:
?- X #= 2*Y, Y = 3.

Note: this is library-specific behaviour. You should probably read the library documentation. I don't think this is generic Prolog question.

Sorry, yes, I am using library(clpfd). That is the only change you will need to make the above code work. As for what I am expecting in response, something like ?- factorial(X, Y) would result in Y = {VAR1} * {VAR1-1} * {VAR1-2}...0 or something? Prolog will return general statements like this for some queries, but I don't know what the difference is between those and this.

@Hayato OK, so my guess was correct. Did you read my answer carefully? Did you think about the three examples I gave you and did you then try it on your computer to see if your expectations meet reality? Did you read the documentation of the library you are using?

I have. The first and third examples yield specific results, while the second just yields the inequality we gave it. From the documentation, library(clpfd) acts through constraint propagation; however, there is no reason shown why the most general query of a rule doesn't or wouldn't return an answer as it is constrained using general variables. In fact, the following example is provided:  ?- X #= 3 #\/ Y #= 4 #<==> B, Y = 4.  will yield  Y = 4, B = 1, X in inf..sup

@Hayato how about the "Note" at the end of my answer? I would still say that this is just how the library happens to work; so a question like "what is the reason for this behavior", if not answered clearly in the docs, should be asked from the designers and implementers of the library. The really simple answer is, if the constraints propagate until a solution is found, you no longer have a symbolic but a concrete solution. This is what example 1 and 3 in my answer demonstrate. So now, a question for you: how does that happen in your "factorial" definition?

My "factorial" definition (1) propagates constraints between X and Y, and then (2) starts guessing values of X for which those constraints hold, instead of (3) returning a set of variables defined by their constraints, such as factorial{VAR2} = {VAR2} * factorial{VAR1}, integer({VAR2}), integer({VAR1}), But you're saying the CLPFD library has been authored to make infinite guesses for input instead of returning a generic solution, and that this is not the behavior of Prolog or SWI-Prolog in and of themselves. Also why do all of my "@" disappear, but I can see yours...?

@Hayato About the disappearing "@", since you are commenting under my answer, I get notified anyway. In the same way I cannot "@" you under your question but I need to "@" you here if I want you to get notified

@Hayato About your comments, you have in fact provided a "constructive proof" in your definition of "factorial", and you hope to get what exactly out of it? Do you know what would be a "closed-form" solution for a factorial? A precursory search tells me that such thing does not in fact exist? Not sure. It does seem however that factorial is an example of a primitive recursive function.
